# Azure B2C Using Claims Resolvers in ClaimsTransformation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to somehow use claims resolvers in a ClaimsTransformation?

This is what I currently have (note the InputParameter):

```
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateRequest" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="email_address" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="content.template_id" DataType="string" Value="template-en"/>
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
```

This is what I'd prefer to have, but doesn't work (Note the InputClaim):

```
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateRequest" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="email_address" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="content.templateId" TransformationClaimType="template_id" DefaultValue="template-{Culture:LanguageCode}" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
```

Is there any way to dynamically generate either an input parameter or input claim to use the {Culture:LanguageCode} claim resolver value? Or perhaps some other indirect way to build up the value of the template_id so that it can choose a language-dependent template?